# Saving HTML with Checkbox states

Tags: html, perl

I am writing a Perl script that is parsing a file into an HTML table which essentially contains classes and their information.  The main objective of the script is for the user to check which classes he needs and the script will read which checkbox states are `TRUE` and only include those when creating a file that is like the original.  Currently, I'm at the point where the HTML file opens in the users default browser, but if I check some of the checkboxes and save the webpage it doesn't save their states (tried it in Chrome and IE).  Is there anyway to do this so that when the file is saved the user can hit enter in the program and have it do its conversion?

Comment: Normally an HTML form would post to a web server of some kind with the values of the form inputs.  Saving a local file would just save the source that's loaded into the browser, not the current state of the DOM.  You might try looking for some sort of DOM parser, but I don't know how you'd get access to it.  It might require some sort of API into the browser itself, which may or may not be available.  Really, the standard way to present a user with an HTML form is to serve it from a web server and post the values back to that server.

Comment: So would it just be easier to avoid the HTML altogether and just do this with checkboxes or a selection window in Tk?

Comment: If you're building a local application and not a web application then yes, that would definitely be the way to go.